# Flask google authentification offline keep

Tags: python, json, google-oauth

I followed [this](http://bitwiser.in/2015/09/09/add-google-login-in-flask.html) tutorial for the authentification with google account in the flask.

As was written in this tutorial the response as the JSON is:

```
{
  "family_name": "Doe", 
  "name": "John Doe", 
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-asdasdas/asdasdad/asdasd/daadsas/photo.jpg", 
  "locale": "en", 
  "gender": "male", 
  "email": "john@gmail.com", 
  "link": "https://plus.google.com/+JohnDoe", 
  "given_name": "John", 
  "id": "1109367330250025112153346", 
  "verified_email": true
}
```

I fetch this JSON response to my database and trying to login in offline mode. In other words, I added one more "group" column to the response and base that column redirect users to the different pages. When I try to log in again with this credentials after login page it opens a blank page without any error. My question how can I keep google user credentials in the flask at offline mode. Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't keep it by this way because oath token will update each time. But you can update user data, at the base of the email. Read [this](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/requests-oauthlib/stable/requests-oauthlib.pdf) guide